# CollectionViewSource as Class Property Type

Tags: wpf, vb.net, collectionviewsource

I have a Class in my main WPF application which has a Property defined in the class as follows:

```
Public Class AppExample
    Public PropertyName As CollectionViewSource
```

The project solution also inherits a Class Library (separate project but included in the solution and using the Inherits statement) - in the Class Library I want to do the same thing but I get an error.

```
Public Class ClassLibraryExample
    Public PropertyName as CollectionViewSource
```

this results in:

> Type 'CollectionViewSource' is not defined

How do I fix this?

Comment: did you include  `System.Windows.Data` namespace in your ClassLibraryExample?

Comment: I can only seem to add System.Windows.Input and System.Windows.Markup in the Class Library. Can't seem to add System.Windows.Data

Comment: aha! I had to add a reference to PresentationFramework. @nit, please add as the answer so I can mark it do you. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the refernce of `PresentationFramework.dll` to your class library. It has namespace `System.Windows.Data` which contains `CollectionViewSource`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using CollectionViewSource  you have to use Data namespace(System.Windows.Data).